# Are There Any Known IE6 Side-Effects From Symantec Endpoint Protection?

Tags: symantec, internet-explorer

> Are There Any Known IE6 Side-Effects From Symantec Endpoint Protection?

- When I view my company's website with IE6 on a QA box with 'Symantec Endpoint Protection' running in the background, the login page is slow.
- Note: I **do not** observe this behavior when viewing this website with IE7 or IE8.

Comment: Can't you simply remove it and see what happens?

Comment: Do you know what features of Symantec Endpoint Protection are installed and enabled?

Comment: Are you excluding the IIS (and other appropriate directories) from the real time scanning engine on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is related to Symantec Endpoint Protection, at least beyond the general  slowness that program brings to the table.

Try disabling the "Network Threat Protection" feature in SEP on the server.  If the problem persists, it seems likely that it is not a SEP issue.

Many websites including those using libraries like jQuery may be taking extra steps to ensure compatibility with IE6.  The disproportionate slowness may be related to other factors

IE6 is a deprecated browser, maybe it's time to stop concerning ourselves with an IE6 user's experience.